# Почему инпут селекта из react-select не сразу отображает inputValue?

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет. У меня есть форма, в которой связаны карта, координаты и вся остальная форма вместе с полем `formatted`, которое с автодополнением. Логика всей формы завязана на координатах:

1. выбираем на карте точку, берутся ее координаты, вставляются значения в `lat, lng`;

ИЛИ

2. вводим координаты;

ИЛИ

3. начинаем вводить адрес и выбираем из автодополнения.

После того, как получили координаты одним из трех способов мы при помощи `googlemaps-api` и этих самых координат получаем все данные и вставляем значения в форму. В третьем случае получается так, что мы вводим в поле `formatted` значение, по нему находим координаты, по этим координатам получаем адрес и заново перезаписываем это поле, по сути, тем же значением. Но не понятно, почему, например, первый вариант(с картой) работает нормально и все сразу отображается, а в третьем варианте оно сетается, но, почему-то, отображается не сразу.
[Видео с демонстрацией](https://youtu.be/oonZy4WM9eM)

```
import { RefAttributes, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { InputSelect, SelectOption } from '@widgets/ui/Select'
import { useAddressPredictions } from '@shared/ui/Map/useAddressPredictions.ts'
import { addressPredictionToOptions, isEmpty } from '@shared/ui/Map/utils.ts'
import { StateManagerProps } from 'react-select/dist/declarations/src/stateManager'
import { useAddress } from '@shared/ui/Map/useAddress.ts'
import { PlaceId } from '@shared/ui/Map/types.ts'
import { Coords } from 'google-map-react'
import { GroupBase, InputActionMeta } from 'react-select/dist/declarations/src/types'
import Select from 'react-select/dist/declarations/src/Select'

interface AddressAutocompleteProps {
  onSelect: (coords: Coords) => void
}

const AddressAutocomplete = <
  Option = unknown,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>,
>({
  inputValue,
  onInputChange,
  onSelect,
  ...props
}: StateManagerProps<Option, IsMulti, Group> &
  RefAttributes<Select<Option, IsMulti, Group>> &
  AddressAutocompleteProps) => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<SelectOption<PlaceId>[] | null>(null)
  const fetchAddressPredictions = useAddressPredictions(inputValue)
  const { getCoordsByPlaceId } = useAddress()

  const handleSelect = useCallback(
    async (v: SelectOption<PlaceId>) => {
      const coords = await getCoordsByPlaceId(v.value)
      onSelect(coords)
    },
    [getCoordsByPlaceId, onSelect],
  )

  const handleFetchPredictionsOptions = useCallback(
    async (v: string) => {
      const res = await fetchAddressPredictions(v)
      setOptions(addressPredictionToOptions(res.predictions))
    },
    [fetchAddressPredictions],
  )
  const handleInputValueChange = useCallback(
    async (v: string, actionMeta: InputActionMeta) => {
      console.log(actionMeta.action)
      if (actionMeta.action !== 'input-change') return

      onInputChange(v, actionMeta)
      if (!isEmpty(v)) {
        await handleFetchPredictionsOptions(v)
      }
    },
    [handleFetchPredictionsOptions, onInputChange],
  )

  return (
    <InputSelect
      placeholder={'Start enter address'}
      {...props}
      options={options ?? undefined}
      onChange={handleSelect}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={handleInputValueChange}
      components={{ DropdownIndicator: null }}
      filterOption={option => option} // we don`t need to filter options
    />
  )
}

export default AddressAutocomplete
```

В форме(react-hook-form) я использую так:

```
<FormField
          control={control}
          name='formatted'
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className={'w-full'}>
              <FormLabel>Formatted</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <AddressAutocomplete
                  name={field.name}
                  ref={field.ref}
                  onBlur={field.onBlur}
                  inputValue={field.value}
                  onInputChange={v => field.onChange(v)}
                  onSelect={setCoords}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
```